# How is the relationship between the table name and entity framework 6 made?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

The name of the table on my database is different from my dbset on my context and my app is working.

Ex: the name of the table is Produtoes and my context contains:

```
public DbSet<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
```

I try to find the word 'Produtoes' on my project and this word doesn't exist.

How is my app working?

Source code: https://github.com/alura-cursos/desenvolvimento-web-asp-net-mvc-5/archive/aula3.zip

To see the situation, just call:

```
localhost:port/produto
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I try to find the word 'Produtoes' on my project and this word doesn't exists.

And you won't find it. That's one of the [Entity Framework Code First Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679962(v=vs.113).aspx), called [PluralizingTableNameConvention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions.pluralizingtablenameconvention(v=vs.113).aspx):

> Represents a convention to set the table name to be a pluralized version of the entity type name.

In English, `Produto` would be pluralized to `Produtoes`, that's the table name.